# Javascript - Switching Between Two Images

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have the following Javascript code which should rapidly switch between two images:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Home Page</title>

    <script src="Resources/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeImage()
        {
            requestAnimationFrame(changeImage);

            var url = document.getElementById('Change_Image').src;

            if (url == 'Resources/Share1.bmp')
            {
                document.getElementById('Change_Image').src = 'Resources/Share2.bmp';
            }

            else
            {
                if (url == 'Resources/Share2.bmp')
                {
                    document.getElementById('Change_Image').src = 'Resources/Share1.bmp';
                }
            }
        }    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h1>Welcome to my Website</h1>
            <h2>Below you can find an example of visual cryptography</h2>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div><img id="Change_Image" src="Resources/Share1.bmp" alt="Letter A" /></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, the code does not work and the image does not change to another one.  What am I doing wrong?  I am quite new to JavaScript so bear with me please?

Comment: I just removed the [tag:C#] tag because you did not mention C# in your question at all, but just to be safe: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: @Nolonar Well actually it does not have to do with C#.  I included the tag because I was programming in ASP.NET which makes use of C#.

Comment: See my answer about using jQuery toggle, one question remains; when do you want to change image? when a user clicks on the image or every couple of seconds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using **assign operator** instead of **comparison operator**. Also use `else if` or just `else` in the second condition.

Change to

```
if (url == 'Resources/Share1.bmp')
```

and

```
else if (url == 'Resources/Share2.bmp')
```

and it should work.

**See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cCvtL/1/) to help you with. It toggles the image with 2 seconds interval**

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Unfortunately, the program still does not switch the images for some reason or another

Comment: put an else between if statement

Comment: now you have to call the changeImage function just after declaring it.

Comment: I included an onclick event to the image to see if the function is being entered.  I also added code to create a pop-up window within the function.  When I click on the image, the pop-up window displays just fine.  The problem is with the logic where I change the image

Comment: use jQuery, it's already included in your page. It'll make scripting a lot easier.

Comment: @Matthew See DEMO at the end of the answer. It can help you

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems to be flawed. Look at this piece of code

```
var url = document.getElementById('Change_Image').src;

            if (url = 'Resources/Share1.bmp')
            {
                document.getElementById('Change_Image').src = 'Resources/Share2.bmp';
            }
```

And your markup is

```
<div><img id="Change_Image" src="Resources/Share1.bmp" alt="Letter A" /></div>
```

The value of url will always be Resources/Share1.bmp. Also as the other posters mentioned equality is == and not =

Answer (score 0):

I see jquery is included, maybe mvc appliction?

You can make use of jquery toggle:
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

your html:

```
<div class="someContainer">
 <img class="Change_Image" src="Resources/Share1.bmp" alt="Letter A" />
 <img class="Change_Image" src="Resources/Share2.bmp" alt="Letter B" style="display:none"/>
</div>
```

your javascript:

```
$(".someContainer").find(".Change_Image").toggle();
```

You want some effects

```
$(".someContainer").find(".Change_Image").toggle("slow");
```