# Javascript – Switching between images with varying intervals

Tags: javascript, image, animation

I’d like to automatically switch between two png images at two different intervals after an initial delay:

1. image A is shown for 2 seconds (the initial delay)
2. image B is shown 0.3 seconds
3. image A is shown for 6 seconds
4. *repeat from step 2*

I found the question [Javascript - Switching Between Two Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948938/javascript-switching-between-two-images) with [letiagoalves’](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1873446/letiagoalves) pedagogical code, showing how to alternate between two images, showing both images for the *same* amount of time:

```
<img id="Change_Image" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="Letter A">

function change_image() {
    var url = document.getElementById('Change_Image').src;
    if (url == 'http://placehold.it/200x200') {
        document.getElementById('Change_Image').src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('Change_Image').src = 'http://placehold.it/200x200';
    }
}

setInterval(change_image, 2000);
```

[(Working demo at jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/cCvtL/1/)

…and have tried to modify it to show the images for *different* amounts of time by using various combinations of `setInterval()` and `setTimeout`, so far to no avail:

1. **Using one `setTimeout()` and two `setInterval()`:**

   - **The thought here** is that image A is shown for a start and `start_animation()` uses a `setTimeout()` to wait for 2 seconds before calling `change_image()` to show image B. In the meantime `change_back()` is called every 0.3 seconds, so that image B is never shown longer than 0.3 seconds, and `change_image()` is called every 6 seconds, so that image B is shown every 6 seconds.
   - **Result – The images switch but the intervals are a bit iffy:** sometimes image B is shown for around the expected time, sometimes it flickers past very briefly. I suppose this is because of interference patterns when `change_image()` and `change_back()` are executing simultaneously.

Code:

```
function start_animation() {
        change_image();
}

function change_image() {
    document.getElementById('Change_Image').src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100';
}

function change_back() {
    document.getElementById('Change_Image').src ='http://placehold.it/200x200';   
}

var initialTimout = 2000; //Time in milliseconds
var longInterval = 6000; //Time in milliseconds
var shortInterval = 300; //Time in milliseconds

setTimeout(start_animation, initialTimout);
setInterval(change_image, longInterval);
setInterval(change_back, shortInterval);
```

[(Working demo at jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Elias_Mossholm/L9yk2dkn/1/)

2. **Using one `setInterval()` and changing the interval as we go along:**

   - **The thought here** is that `change_image()` takes care of all the image changes and depending on which image is shown, the interval of `setInterval` is changed.
   - **Result – This solution shows both images for the same time** (the initial timeout time), which is not what the goal was. I looked into how to change variables outside the function but must either have gotten it wrong or JS doesn’t allow the interval to be changed once `setInterval()` has been called.

Code:

```
interval = 2000;

function change_image() {
    var url = document.getElementById('Change_Image').src;
    if (url == 'http://placehold.it/200x200') {
        document.getElementById('Change_Image').src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100';
        window.interval = 300;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('Change_Image').src = 'http://placehold.it/200x200';
        window.interval = 6000;
    }
}

setInterval(change_image, interval);
```

[(Working demo at jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Elias_Mossholm/88y36yxn/3/)

3. **Using consecutive `setTimeout()`’s:**

   - **The thought here** is to let `change_image()` and `change_back()` call each other over and over after an initial 2 second timeout and to use `setTimeout()` to make sure the calls are delayed and the timing between them is right.
   - **Result – Doesn’t seem to work at all:** only image A is shown.

Code:

```
function start_animation() {
    change_image();
}

function change_image() {
    document.getElementById('Change_Image').src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100';
    change_back();
}

function change_back() {
    document.getElementById('Change_Image').src ='http://placehold.it/200x200';   
}


setTimeout(start_animation, 2000);
setTimeout(change_back(), 300);
setTimeout(change_image(),6000);
```

[(Working demo at jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Elias_Mossholm/uc7nuc1c/1/)

**Is there a good way to solve this in Javascript?**

**How?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using consecutive `setTimeouts` is the way to go (#3).

Multiple intervals (or intervals at all) will get messy as you try to switch between 300ms to 6000ms. You're looking at either clearing the interval or trying to "sync" up your image swaps in a way that kind of, sort of works (but if you let it run long enough, you'll see image A swapping too quickly with image B and so on).

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates the consecutive timeouts:

http://jsfiddle.net/cCvtL/43/

For your example code, instead of setting your timers all at once, you want to set them consecutively, after the timer has run. For the initial timeout value of `2000`, we check against an `undefined` value (from the initial looper call). After that, we pass the args `300` or `6000` from our `setTimeouts`.

```
function looper(url, interval){
    // If interval is undefined, we set the value to 2000 (initial)
    // Otherwise, we use the value passed in
    interval = interval === undefined ? 2000 : interval;

    // If url is present, we switch the image source
    if (url) {
        document.getElementById('Change_Image').src = url;
    } else {
        // Default, to keep things tidy.
        url = "http://placehold.it/200x200";
    }

    // Timer logic to handle the next iteration
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (url === "http://placehold.it/200x200") {
            looper("http://placehold.it/100x100", 300);
        } else {
            looper("http://placehold.it/200x200", 6000);
        }
    }, interval);
}

// Kick off the timer!
looper();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, [Promise](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) could help here ; would this general (completely untested, pseudo-codish) idea make sense in your case ? (Here, using something like [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird))

```
// Show an image, and returns a promise resolved after a number of ms 
var showImage = function (src, howLong) {

   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

     document.getElementById('Change_Image').src = src
     setTimeout(resolve, howLong)

   });

}


// The loop part
var recur = function loop() {
  return showImage("url-of-imageB",300).then(function () {
       return showImage("url-of-imageA",6000)
  }).then(recur);
}

// Show A, then loop
showImage("url-of-imageA",2000).then(recur);
```

Comment: Thanks @phtrivier, would promises (I didn’t know about them, had to read up on them) add any particular benefit to the end users or to me in this case? (Like not blocking the execution at the user’s side as much / being quicker.)

Comment: I think they would add much in term of clarity of the code, which is a good thing in itself ! Besides, using promise to represent asynchronous behavior adds the possibility to *compose* asynchronous functions in interesting ways (look at Promise.all, Promise.catch, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple trick,  you almost got it you just need to put timeouts

```
function change_image() {
    var url = document.getElementById('Change_Image').src;
    console.log(url);
    if (url == 'wdw.tv.png') {
        setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById('Change_Image').src = 'slmn.png';
            }, 2000);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById('Change_Image').src = 'wdw.tv.png';
            }, 2000);
    }
}

setInterval(change_image, 4000);
```

Initial delay is 4 seconds,  it will shown image A after 2 seconds then from that point on it will switch between the two every 2 seconds.

Just play around with the interval.  Though if you have more images it will be different.
Hope this helps you get going.

And here is the **[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vryxxn40/)**

******EDIT******

According to the comment below, this can remove the erratic behavior

```
function change_image(url) {
    if(url){
        document.getElementById('Change_Image').src= url;
    }
    if (url == 'img1.png') {
        window.setTimeout(change_image, 300, 'img2.gif');
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(change_image, 6000, 'img1.png');
    }
}

setTimeout(change_image(), 2000);
```

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vryxxn40/2/)**

Comment: I tried the jsfiddle demo and it is very erratic. I also think this will run into the same problems I had in example two, with the overall setInterval conflicting with the inner setTimeouts. But thanks for giving it a try! I appreciate it.

Comment: Just to clarify: the code as it is alternates between the images every 4s instead of every 2s, without being erratic. Setting <code>setInterval</code> to 2s and the inner <code>setTimeout</code>s to 0,3 and 6,0 s respectively yields the erratic behaviour I mentioned in the previous comment.